# meteor js (meteor-autoform + iron router) pass value after form is submitted

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router, meteor-autoform

After a form is successfully validated I would like to redirect the user to a specific page and display some values. I don't know if the way I think to use is the correct one. Here's what I tried already:

creating form in template:

```
{{> quickForm collection="Transactions" id="insertTransaction" type="insert"}}
```

then I created the hook to get called when form is validated & inserted

```
AutoForm.addHooks('insertTransaction',{
  onSuccess: function(data){
    Router.go('one', null, {query: 'amount=' + data->amount});
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

@Michel Floyd

my one.html

```
<template name="one">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-7">
       One Page...
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
        {{ amount }}
    </div>
</div>
</template>
```

My code from home.js (client/home.js):

```
AutoForm.addHooks('insertTransaction',{
onSuccess: function(data, data2, data3){

    result = Transactions.findOne(data2, { amount: 1});
    amount = (result["amount"]);
    Router.go('one',{amount: amount});
}
});
```

Here's my router code:

```
Router.route('/one/:amount',()=>{
name: 'one',
this.render('one', {data: this.params.amount});
});
```

I get "No route found named "one"" all the time.

Comment: the idea seems reasonable to me.

Comment: It seem's like using `data->amount` is not working. When I use only data to pass as GET parameter `data` I get only "insert". How to access the values itself?

Comment: wouldn't that be data.amount? but i don't use IronRouter, so i'm not really clear on what's happening on that line. i was just saying the overall idea seems reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

First Create a route with `amount` as a param, i.e.

```
Router.route('/one/:amount',()=>{
  name: 'one',
  this.render('one', {data: this.params.amount});
});
```

Then use `Router.go('one',{amount: amount});`

Note that there's no underscore next to `amount` in `this.params.amount`

Comment: How to create the route? I posted my code into first post.

Comment: This is soo strange, please check my update on first post. It's that kind of strange. Now it doesn't find the template.

Comment: Do you have a layout template that you're using as well? Normally individual routes are rendered into a `{{> yield}}` inside a layout template.